# Rsyslog is not installed after successfully executing "sudo make install" using source file

Tags: linux, logs, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I need mmaudit plugin for converting system audit logs into JSON formatted logs. But mmaudit is not available with standard versions. so I decided to work with source files from  GitHub. I followed these steps. After installing required tools.

```
git clone https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog.git   

autoreconf -fvi

./configure
```

[image]

uncommented required modules

```
make

sudo make install
```

these cmds run without any error and but still

```
service rsyslog start/restart/status
```

shows

```
rsyslog : unrecognized service
```

Comment: Do you have `systemd`? Maybe the installation only works under this one

Comment: no I'm running it inside a docker container

Comment: Did you solve it? I saw you asked another question and I thought you may be have resolved this question.

Comment: Installed into `/usr/local`? Of course it won't work.

Comment: yes . it installed in  `/usr/local` . how to start it now